# Get the set of edges of a graph in O(m+k) in Python

Tags: python, graph, complexity-theory

I want to get **the set of edges** of the following *graph* in **O(m+k)**, k = number of edges, m = number of vertices

```
#graph
def define_G():
    m = 5
    G = [set() for _ in range(m)]
    G[0] |= {1,2}
    G[1] |= {0,2,3,4}
    G[2] |= {0,1,4}
    G[3] |= {1,4}
    G[4] |= {1,2,3}
    return G
```

I wrote this code but it seems to run in O(m^2):

```
def edgeset(G):
  m = set()
  i = 0
  for a in G:
    for b in a:
      m.add(frozenset({i, b}))
    i += 1
```

It returns `set([frozenset([2, 4]), frozenset([6, 7]), frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 6]), frozenset([1, 4]), frozenset([8, 9]), frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([0, 2]), frozenset([4, 5]), frozenset([1, 3]), frozenset([2, 7]), frozenset([0, 1])])`, but not in `O(m+k)`. How is it possible in `O(m+k)`?

Comment: Your time complexity can't be `O(m**2)`; the worst it could be is `O(mk)`. Your inner loop doesn't range over all the vertices, but over the edges of the current vertex. There are `k` edges, so `2k` vertex-edge entries so the inner loop can't possibly be more than `2k/m` time. And the inside of the loop is obviously constant. So, `O(m * 2k/m * 1) = O(mk)`.

Comment: But it's not even that—the total number of times through the inner loop, across all outer loops, must be 2k. Iterating the outer loop, including whatever work is needed to do that 2k looping, is at worst an extra m steps. And `O(m + 2k) = O(m+k)`.

Comment: @abarnert The equation `O(m * 2k/m * 1) = O(mk)` in your first comment is misleading. In the extreme, k = O(m**2), so it is `O(m * 2 * m**2 / m * 1)`, which simplifies to `O(m**2)` and not `O(mk)`, and otherwise simplifies to `O(2k)`.

Comment: @mu無 Sure, and if `k = m**2`, then `O(m+k)` is also `O(m**2)`. So what?

Comment: @abarnert Well, `O(mk)` complexity means in the worst case it is `O(m * m**2)`, which is `O(m**3)`. That's all I'm saying, the O(mk) is misleading.

Comment: @mu無 Did you not read the second comment, that starts "But it's not even that" and leads to the conclusion that it's always `O(m+k)`, not `O(mk)`?

Comment: @abarnert It is clear to me. I'm just pointing that the `O(m * 2k/m * 1) = O(mk)` equation in the first comment is misleading in the first place, that's all. _It can not simplify to `O(mk)`_.

Comment: On a side note, `edgeset` can be written as:
`{(i, j) if i < j else (j, i) for i, a in enumerate(g) for j in a}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it is `O(m**2)` always?

In one extreme case, all the nodes can be connected with edges, which means you will iterate through every edge exactly twice, making this `O(k)` solution. Note that though `k` is `O(m**2)` in this situation, since total number of edges possible = `m C 2`, your solution can still be represented as O(m+k).

In the other extreme case, none of the nodes are connected, which means you have to iterate all the empty vertices exactly once, making this an O(m) solution. Since k is zero/ constant, this is still `O(m+k)` solution.

So overall, your solution is always `O(m+k)`.

Comment: I thought, it was O(m*k) because of the 2 loops, but thanks for your answer. Is the comment of arbanert under my question also what you meant? "And O(m + 2k) = O(m+k)"

Comment: @Alpha I've left a comment below @abarnert comments to explain why it is not `O(mk)`. Also, `O(m + 2k) = O(m+k)` is true, in the order notation analysis, the *constant* multipliers do not change the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

As every edge occurs only twice in total in all neighbor sets, the sum of sizes of neigbor sets is 2 x k. Meaning your code is O(m+k).